# $\overline{f(z)}$ is differentiable if and only if $f'(a)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

[image]

*Proof:*

[image]

> I don't understand why $\left|\frac{\overline{h}}{h}\right|$ should be equal to $1$ when $f'(z_0)=0$. Can someone please explain?

Comment: $\left|\frac{\bar h}h\right| = 1$ ALWAYS (when $h\ne 0$). You're not parsing the sentence correctly.

Comment: @TedShifrin Why does the same argument not apply in the case where $f'(z_0)\ne 0$? That is, if we apply modulus to both sides, then we should get $|k'(z_0)| = | f'(z_0) |\cdot 1$ regardless of the value of $f'(z_0)$ and regardless of whether or not $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{\bar{h}}{h}$ exists.

Comment: Think of something analogous even with real numbers. If $|g(x)|$ has a limit as $x\to x_0$, does it follow that $g(x)$ has a limit as $x\to x_0$?

Comment: Closely related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863266/prove-that-overlinefz-is-differentiable-at-a-in-d01-if-and-only-if?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $h \not = 0$, then $|\frac{\overline{h}}{h}| = \frac{|\overline{h}|}{|h|} = 1$.

Comment: Why does the same argument not apply to the case where $f'(z_0)\ne 0$? That is, if we apply modulus to both sides, then we should get $|k'(z_0)| = | f'(z_0) |\cdot 1$ regardless of the value of $f'(z_0)$ and regardless of whether or not $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{\bar{h}}{h}$ exists.

Comment: Because you don't know if $k'(z_0)$ exists... The reason why $|\overline{h}/h| = 1$ is important is that it implies in particular that $\overline{h}/h$ does not blow up to infinity, i.e. it is bounded. So we are multiplying something that is bounded, by something going to $0$, so we get $0$.

Comment: If $f'(z_0) \not = 0$, then the fact that $\overline{h}/h$ doesn't converge is important. It's no longer rendered irrelevant by a term converging to $0$. Without trying to be rude, it seems your issue is with limits themselves rather than complex analysis.

Comment: In terms of rigour, why is it plausible to multiply something going to $0$ by something that does not have a limit? In the sense that aren't we multiplying something that does not exist by $0$? This is what concerns me.  @mathworker21

Comment: Claim: If $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and $|g(x)| \le M$ for all $x$, then $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x) = 0$.

.

Proof: Take $\epsilon > 0$. Take $\delta > 0$ so that $|x| < \delta \implies |f(x)| < \epsilon/M$, which we can do since $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. Then, for $|x| < \delta$, $|f(x)g(x)| < \epsilon$. We have thus shown $f(x)g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: To answer your last question (which is a good question), we are not multiplying $0$ by something that doesn't exist. Using the notation in my most recent answer, we are *not* doing $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x) = [\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)]\cdot [\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)]$, since we don't know if $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ exists. What we are doing, is saying that the possibly erratic behavior of $g$ does not matter, since $f$ is going to $0$ and thus dominates things.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification, now it makes sense to me. @mathworker

Answer (score 0):

When $f'(z_0)=0$, taking modulus on both sides we get 
$$|k'(z_0)| \le \left|\left( \overline {\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}}\right)\right|\left|\frac{\bar{h}}{h}\right| =\left|\left(\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}\right)\right|$$

(Since $\left|\frac{\bar{h}}{h}\right|=1$).Taking limits on both sides we get the result.

Comment: Why is there this division between $f'(z_0)=0$ and $f'(z_0)\ne0$? The problem is that if $\left| \frac{\bar{h}}{h}\right|=1$ then why do we care what $f'(z_0)$ is? That is, if we apply modulus to both sides, then we should get $|k'(z_0)| = | f'(z_0) |\cdot 1$, so that we shouldn't care whether or not $f'(z_0)=0$ and whether or not $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{\bar{h}}{h}$ exists.

Comment: @sequence Observe that I have taken the limit after using the fact that $|\frac{\bar{h}}{h}|=1$.  If $f'(z_0) \ne 0$, then the limit of right hand side doesn't exist. Had it existed, then you can divide by $f'(z_0)$ to get that the limit of $\frac{\bar{h}}{h}$ exists which is not true. If $f'(z_0)=0$, then you need to make sure that the thing you are multiplying to it is bounded. That's why the separation.

Comment: Then for the case where $f'(z_0)=0$ we should be able to divide by $f'(z_0)$ to recover the limit of $\frac{\bar{h}}{h}$. Of course, we cannot divide by $0$, but how does this imply that we're allowed to use this "trick"? Still unclear.  @tattwamasi amrutam

Comment: @sequence Like you said one cannot divide by $0$. But $f'(z_0)=0$  anyway. So I just need to make sure that whatever thing I am multiplying to it is bounded which is exactly what is happening.

Comment: Speaking of rigour, why is it plausible to multiply something going to $0$ by something that does not have a limit? In the sense that aren't we multiplying something that does not exist by $0$? This is what concerns me, and I believe this is too important to not pay attention to this detail. @tattwamasi amrutam

Comment: The bound is a constant. Multiplying it by $0$ is $0$. The left hand side is in modulus which is always bigger than or equal to $0$. Sometimes it is known as squeeze theorem.

Comment: But consider this: $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} g(z) \frac{\bar{h}}{h}$. We know that $g(z)$ goes to $f'(z_0)=0$, and at the same time $\frac{\bar{h}}{h}$ does not exist as $h\to 0$. So there seems to be a contradiction of a kind, when one part of the product has a limit, but the other part of the product has no limit. So that $f'(z_0)$ goes to $0$, but $\frac{\bar{h}}{h}$ goes to nowhere, so that we multiply something that goes to a number by something that goes nowhere (goes to something that does not exist).

Comment: Now, if we can multiply $0$ by something that does not exist, why can't we multiply any other number by something that does not exist, rigorously speaking?

Comment: I am not looking at $\frac{\bar{h}}{h}$. I am looking at its upper bound which is $1$.

Comment: Why are you looking at the upper bound in the case of $0$ and not looking at it in the case of non-zero? Because you assume that if $|\bar{h}/h|$ does not go to infinity, then you can safely multiply it by $0$. This implies that we can multiply by $0$ non-existent limits, which we cannot multiply by non-zero numbers.

Comment: Because in the case when it is no zero, I have to show that the limit doesn't exist. Bounding by $1$ doesn't give you anything.